Search a JSON with multiple array elements for specific attribute and get another attribute value
I am using SQL Server 2019 and need to search for arrays in JSON that contains specific attribute. And get the latest value of another attribute. My JSON looks like this:
{
    "Comment":[
        {"Id":"1","CreateTime":"20241001","UpdateTime":0,"value":"aaa"}
        ,{"Id":"2","CreateTime":"20241002","UpdateTime":0,"User":"A","Result":"bbb"}
        ,{"Id":"3","CreateTime":"20241003","UpdateTime":0,"value":"ccc"}
        ,{"Id":"4","CreateTime":"20241004","UpdateTime":0,"User":"B","Result":"ddd"}
    ]
}

I need to search for arrays that contain attribute User. In my sample those are arrays with an Id 2 and 4. And I need to get the value of an attribute Result for Id 4, because it has latest CreateTime. So query must return ddd
I tried to write a query with JSON_QUERY() with no success. I would really appreciate some help or tips to solve my issue.

What exactly is your current attempt?

Wouldn't you want OPENJSON? It's not entirely clear what your expected results are here, as you don't provide any.

It's usually hard to use JSON_QUERY with arrays, have you checked out OPENJSON? It allows to get the above in a table form where it's easy to search for values with your favourite sql toolset

The actual statement depends on the JSON structure. In this situation a possible approach is to parse the JSON content with OPENJSON() and the appropriate schema, transform it into a table and get the expected result:
JSON:
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = N'{
    "Comment":[
        {"Id":"1","CreateTime":"20241001","UpdateTime":0,"value":"aaa"}
        ,{"Id":"2","CreateTime":"20241002","UpdateTime":0,"User":"A","Result":"bbb"}
        ,{"Id":"3","CreateTime":"20241003","UpdateTime":0,"value":"ccc"}
        ,{"Id":"4","CreateTime":"20241004","UpdateTime":0,"User":"B","Result":"ddd"}
    ]
}'

Statement:
SELECT TOP 1 [Result]
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.Comment') WITH (
   [User] nvarchar(10) '$.User',
   [Result] nvarchar(10) '$.Result',
   [CreateTime] varchar(10) '$.CreateTime'
)
WHERE [User] IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY TRY_CONVERT(date, [CreateTime]) DESC

Also note, that the $.Comment part of the stored JSON is an array, containing JSON objects, not JSON arrays.

Thank you very much! That is exactly what I needed
